# Alternative of sails-skipper for upload?

Tags: node.js, upload, sails.js, sails-skipper

I have a big issue with **[sails-skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper)**.
Sometimes it work fine, but mostly when i post the file(with meta fields) then it flushes out body. `console.log(req.body)` prints`{}`.

I have posted this ***issue*** here **[#138](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/issues/138)**.

Is there any other library which works fine with sails ?

I find a name **[multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)**, is it good and how to implement it in sails ?

Answer (score 0):

There are `connect-multipart`, `busboy`, `formidable`. I've tried some of them, but reverted back to `skipper`.